In which topology on $X^*$, $X^*$ is a barrel space where $X^*$ is the dual of a Banach space $X$.
In a locally convex linear topological space $X,$ any convex, balanced and absorbing closed set is called a barrel. $X$ is called a barrel space if each of its barrels is a neighbourhood of zero.
And we know that a subset $M$ of a topological space $X$ is said to be non-dense in $X$ if the closure $M^\text{a}$ does not contain a non-void open set of $X$.
$M$ is called dense in $X$ if $M^\text{a} = X.$ $M$ is said to be of the first category if $M$ is expressible as the union of a countable number of sets each of which is non-dense in $X$; otherwise $M$ is said to be of the second category.
theorem
A locally convex linear topological space $X$ is a barrel space if $X$ is not of the first category.
As an example all Banach spaces are barrel spaces.
So my question is
if we have a Banach space $X$ so its dual $X^*$ is also a Banach space so $X^*$ is a barrel space but in which topology on $X^*$ any convex, balanced and absorbing closed set is a neighbourhood of 0.

"in which topology any convex, balanced and absorbing closed set is a neighbourhood of 0?"  In the norm topology of $X^*$.  Or are you asking whether other topologies will also be barrel spaces?

yes, i want to know whether other topologies will also be barrel spaces.
